# Two basic Tortoise SubVersion questions

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm new to  SubVersion and I have two really basic questions.

I would like to import an existing Eclipse project using TortoiseSVN.  The web page on 'Import in place' `http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-import.html` says
*"... create a new project folder in the  repository"*.

Question one: does this assume the same name for the SubVersion repository and the Eclipse project?

Question two:  Import in Place.step 2 says:  *"Checkout the new folder over the top of the folder you  want to import"*.  What does "*...over the top*" mean in this  context, the folder above the
project, in my case C:/eclipse_workspace or the actual project root in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

1- no need to get same name you can change directory in checkout windows

2-In my case I used checkout inside workspace folder

> workspace/project folder

and the project folder is checked out from repo

Answer (score 0):

I think you should really use a Subversion plugin for Eclipse. I use [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) and it does everything I need.